# Error trying to stream multiple files - Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i mylist.txt -f mpegts -vcodec copy -acodec copy http://localhost:8081/yoursecret`

mylist.txt file contains:

```
file 'out001.ts'
file 'out002.ts'
```

*up to out327.ts*

Here's the output of the above command:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-04-03-52523b6 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 77.101 / 58. 77.101
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
mylist.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

However streaming individual files works:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i out001.ts -f mpegts -vcodec copy -acodec copy http://localhost:8081/yoursecret
```

I've also tried but also does not work:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i <(for %%i in (*.ts) do @echo file '%%i') -f mpegts -vcodec copy -acodec copy http://localhost:8081/yoursecret
```

Comment: Did you verify that **all** inputs are valid?

Comment: Yes I did  check

Comment: Check that `mylist.txt` does not have any invalid or special characters.